# How do I create a seed file using a model with references? I'm not sure I set up the models correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to know if I've set up the models correctly.

I'm starting a new rails project which includes user, item, and order models. There will also be vendors, but as a reference to the User model. I'm not sure that I set up my models correctly, because when I created a seed file I got an error message 'ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Vendor must exist'. Does this mean that I should create a Vendor model instead of a User reference of Vendor? Including all my model files and seed file. Please let me know if my issue is unclear.

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :vendor, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key  => "vendor_id"
  has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
end

class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :vendor, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key  => "vendor_id"
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :items

  def readable_date
    self.date.strftime("%b %d, %Y")
  end

  def deliver
    self.delivered = true
    self.user.balance -= 5
  end

end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :orders
  has_many :items, :through => :orders


  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
     where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
       user.provider = auth.provider
       user.uid = auth.uid
       user.email = auth.info.email
       user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
     end
  end

end

#seeds.rb -------------------------------------------------------------

brittany = User.create(user_name: "Brittany", email: "brittanygrebnova@gmail.com", password: "mila2013", street_address: "223 Washburn Ave.", city: "Washington", state: "NJ", balance: 25 )
lana = User.create(user_name: "Lana", email: "lanagrebnova@gmail.com", password: "bony2015", street_address: "15 Schley Rd.", city: "Far Hills", state: "NJ", balance: 25 )

burrito = Item.create(name: "burrito", price: 8, vendor_id: 1)
tacos = Item.create(name: "tacos", price: 7, vendor_id: 1)
churros = Item.create(name: "churros", price: 6, vendor_id: 1)

pizza = Item.create(name: "slice a pizza", price: 3, vendor_id: 2)
garlic_knots = Item.create(name: "10 garlic knots", price: 5, vendor_id: 2)
tiramisu = Item.create(name: "tiramisu", price: 4, vendor_id: 2)

red_curry = Item.create(name: "red curry", price: 10, vendor_id: 3)
drunken_noodles = Item.create(name: "drunken noodles", price: 12, vendor_id: 3)
coconut_pudding = Item.create(name: "coconut pudding", price: 7, vendor_id: 3)

first_order = Order.create(date: Date.today, vendor_id: 1, user_id: 1)
first_order.items = burrito, churros

second_order = Order.create(date: Date.today, vendor_id: 2, user_id: 2)
second_order.items = red_curry, coconut_pudding

------------------------------------------------------------------------

#schema.rb -------------------------------------------------------------

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_01_11_164506) do

  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "price"
    t.integer "vendor_id"
  end

  create_table "items_orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "item_id"
    t.integer "order_id"
  end

  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.datetime "date"
    t.string "vendor_id"
    t.string "user_id"
    t.integer "delivery_charge", default: 5
    t.boolean "delivered"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "provider"
    t.string "uid"
    t.string "user_name"
    t.string "street_address"
    t.string "city"
    t.integer "balance"
    t.string "state"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I expect that an item and order can have a vendor_id, that a vendor has_many orders and has_many items, and that a vendor is a reference to the User model (checkbox at signup if vendor).

Comment: The models look ok. What does your seed file look like?

Comment: No, you don't have to create a vendor model as your associations looks correct but when seeding data don't use hardcoded ids as vasfed suggested.. if you want you can also use the existing `user` object to create records in associated models so for example for user `lana` you can create a burrito item by doing something like below: 


`burrito = lana.items.create!(name: "burrito", price: 8)` 

You can also try these queries in [rails console](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-console) executing them one by one to learn and understand the sql that gets generated.

Comment: After trying it out in the console, I decided to go with a vendor model. I removed the hard coded id's per your suggestion and everything seems to be working as it should on a basic level. Time to code more! Thank you for your answers : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardcoding ids is not a good practice (even when your db is empty - new record is not guaranteed to have id 1),

In your seeds - pass objects, like:

```
lana = User.create(user_name: "Lana", email: "lanagrebnova@gmail.com", password: "bony2015", street_address: "15 Schley Rd.", city: "Far Hills", state: "NJ", balance: 25 )
burrito = Item.create(name: "burrito", price: 8, vendor: lana)
```